# How do I execute a function after each set of tests?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I was doing some tests with JUNIT, and i am using a parameterized design where i can feed in large sets of information such as following:

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection testList(){
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            {"chrome", new ChromeDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome())},
            {"firefox", new FirefoxDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox())}
    });
}
```

So, my class, would run all of its tests twice; with each of those sets.

It seems that using `@AfterClass` will fire after the entire set has finished.  `@After` fires after each test.  How would I fire a function, after it iterating  1 item in the above collection?

Right now when i run it, it will run 2 iterations of 4 tests.  After each iteration i need to fire a maintenance script.

The reason i have discovered is that after the first iteration of tests, it will hang until the browser closes.  I dont want to close the browser until the iteration has completed.

Comment: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/45

Comment: Dang, I was really hoping it was a thing